# Observable Array Map not working - Duplicate data on change

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I have a home screen on an Ionic Firebase/GeoFire app which should show the people close by.

The function is set to return an observable of the array of users close by and the observable is set to map the arrays values, so why does the home screen show duplicate data if a person  updates their name or changes their location.. it will add another member to the screen along with the old one.

```
 public outputUsersCloseToMe(userSettingDistance ? ): Observable < Array < iUserModel >> {

  let availableUsers = < Array < iUserModel >> [];

  this.firebaseInit().database().ref("users").child(this.profile().uid).child('profile').child('lastKnownLocation').once('value').then((snapshot) => {

    const args = {
      center: [snapshot.val().lat, snapshot.val().lng],
      radius: parseInt(userSettingDistance, 10)
    }; //kilometers

    this.geoFire.query(args).on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {

      this.firebaseInit().database().ref('users').child(key).child('profile').on('value', (usr) => {

        if (usr.val() && usr.val().id != this.profile().uid) {

          availableUsers.push({
            id: usr.val().id,
            birthday: usr.val().birthday,
            gender: usr.val().gender,
            distance: distance.toFixed(2),
            location: location,
            firstName: usr.val().firstName,
            userAvatar: (!usr.val().avatarUrl ? "../assets/img/generic.png" : usr.val().avatarUrl),
          });

        }

      });
    });
  });

  return Observable.from([availableUsers]).map(val => val);
}
```

Comment: You are just pushing new values to existing array... ?

Comment: Yeah but how do I achieve what I am looking for.. currently i am just splicing any duplicate data from the array which works but doesnt feel like im utilizing observables stuff to their fullest potential.